# How to create boolean variable in a stored procedure using db2?

Tags: sql, db2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteNotActualData()
SPECIFIC proc_vars
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

DECLARE trueOrFalse BOOLEAN;

END;
```

When I try to do this query I have an:

> error: 42601  A character, token, or clause is invalid or missing.

Comment: Perfectly fine ANSI SQL syntax. (Works fine with Mimer SQL.)

Comment: Pavel, comments in English please!

Comment: it isn't working in db2 9.1 and @ character don't need for it.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about DB2 for LUW, the `BOOLEAN` data type is available from version 9.7 onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify separator and change **BOOLEAN** to **SMALLINT**

This is example:

```
--/
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteNotActualData()
SPECIFIC proc_vars
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

DECLARE trueOrFalse SMALLINT;

END
/
```

Answer (score 1):

DB2 9.1 for LUW doesn't have a boolean type.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0008483.htm

Boolean is available in 10.5, not sure when it was added.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0055394.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-2-3-0-7